# CSS to avoid the image alt text getting displayed in print preview

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In IE 8, I am seeing the alt text getting displayed in the print preview when the image is not getting displayed.The issue is not occurring in chrome. I want to fix this issue in IE 8.

Src of the image gets added in run time. At some times images will not be available from the server

> `<img src="null" alt="weird issue">`

Needed a fix without using javascript

Comment: But that's exactly what the alt ("alternative") text is there for, no? Why is the image not available in the first place?

Comment: @Pekka웃 But why doesn't it then show up in chrome?

Comment: Src of the image gets added in run time. At some times images will not be available from the server

Comment: @bwoebi no idea, maybe Chrome treats the alt property differently. Still, IE8 seems to be doing it correctly

Comment: @Pekka웃 yeah, that's what's wondering me. Chrome buggying, but IE correct?!

Comment: @bwoebi yeah, strange! Maybe using `alt` for this purpose has become impractical... no idea. Ravi, I think you will have to remove the `alt` property using JavaScript. In jQuery: `$("img").attr("alt", "");`

Comment: Thanks @bwoebi for the suggestion. But I need the fix without using js

Comment: @Ravi - the answer I've posted below is a CSS solution.  I'm not clear why it's not suitable.  If you give us more details, we can help you.

Comment: If the image is not available, then the `alt` attribute value should be used in its stead. If this is not suitable, then the `alt` attribute value has not been written adequately. (If the adequate textual replacement is no text, you should use `alt=""`.) It seems that you are solving the wrong problem; you should ask why Chrome fails to implement the `alt` attribute properly (on screen and in print).

Answer (score 1):

You can't style the alt text directly, but it will inherit from the `img` parent so probably the easiest is to simply set the `color` of your `img` to white in the CSS (and if for print applications, then within your print styles).

Try this:

```
img{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

In that example, I've also set the `background-color` to white but this probably isn't 100% necessary given that if this is a print style, the background will inevitably be white anyway.

As has been mentioned in the comments below this answer, you may be able to use a CSS [attribute selector](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) to only target those imgs that have `'null'` as their source.

This would work like this:

```
img[src="null"]{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

This would, however, come with a few additional requirements/assumptions:

- That the src is indeed 'null', and not just an ampty string (in which case you could use `img[src=""]`).
- CSS attribute selectors work in IE7 and up.  However, IE7 and IE8 are a little delicate to `!DOCTYPE` declarations so you have to ensure that your page has a valid `!DOCTYPE` declared.
- Older browsers (IE6, for example) will not support this, so you'll still get the alt text come through.
- Assumes that a CSS resolution is actually what you're asking for, and - as before - that the background the image sits on is indeed white!

You could extend upon ths use of attribute selectors to simply ensure that those images coming through with `src="null"` aren't displayed at all:

```
img[src="null"]{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I can not use the background color and color. needed a way not to display using css

Comment: css is color/background-color

Comment: Hi @Ravi, it might be worth updating your question in that case.  It's not clear what you can/can't do with the CSS.

Comment: Unsure what you mean @albert?

Comment: he said that he can't use your solution. but that he wants a css solution. which yours is. so i'm confused. pretty slick, btw.

Comment: Ah thanks @albert, that makes more sense.  Updated the question to make it all the more obvious that it's a CSS solution!  I thought for a minute I had spelt it 'colour' (British spelling for 'color', doesn't work in CSS) and that's what you were picking up on.

Comment: @Brewal - great suggestion!  It should work as long as the page has a valid `!DOCTYPE`.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For mozilla : study this code and find a way to achieve it with other browsers.

```
img:-moz-broken:before,
input:-moz-broken:before,
img:-moz-user-disabled:before,
input:-moz-user-disabled:before,
img:-moz-loading:before,
input:-moz-loading:before,
applet:-moz-empty-except-children-with-localname(param):-moz-broken:before,
applet:-moz-empty-except-children-with-localname(param):-moz-user-disabled:before {
    content: -moz-alt-content !important;
    unicode-bidi: -moz-isolate;
}
```

Or, some absolutely basic inline javascript, some verry ugly old-school inline event handler:

```
<img src="broken.png" onerror="this.style.display='none'" />
```